# nullPointerException using AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream more than once

Tags: java, audio, nullpointerexception, mp3, decode

For a few days I have been looking for ways to decode an MP3, change the samplingRate and re-encode it to MP3.
Now that is works, I have put it in a loop because I need to repeat the process multiple times.

"Rates" are a floating variable representing by how much i'll multiply the speed of the audio file.

For context here is when I call my function a bunch of times :

```
    private void passRates() throws Exception {
        for (Float rate : this.rates) {
            String audio = "Some file name.mp3"
            createAudio(audio, rate);
                for (Beatmap beatmap : this.currentBeatmaps) {
                    createRate(beatmap, audio, rate);
            }
        }
    }
```

The createAudio() function calls a class "ConvertMP3" that creates a new audio file once, and the nullPointerException happens in it.

Here the buggy part:

```
        AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.source);
        AudioFormat baseFormat = in.getFormat();
        AudioFormat decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
            baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
            16,
            baseFormat.getChannels(),
            baseFormat.getChannels() * 2,
            baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
            false);
        AudioInputStream din = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in);
```

The last line that calls to AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream() only works for the first iteration. All iterations happens for the same audio file and every parameter is "new" for each iteration, so I don't understand how something could be null.

Here is the last segment of the error log:

```
mai 18, 2017 6:57:18 PM beatmaptweaker.menus.MultipleRate 
jButtonStartRatingMouseClicked
GRAVE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat.matches(AudioFormat.java:450)
at javax.sound.sampled.spi.FormatConversionProvider.isConversionSupported(FormatConversionProvider.java:169)
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:968)
at beatmaptweaker.customClasses.ConvertMP3.newRatedMusicFile(ConvertMP3.java:56)
```

The error seems to trigger when comparing two AudioFormat objects (The ones that I just instanciated before calling getAudioInputStream and that are strictly identical on each iteration of my loop)

So I am stuck here, I hope someone can figure this out :/

Update 1: I didn't close the AudioInpuStream in my code. Now that I did it, it still doesn't work.

Update 2: The error comes from inside javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat, because it checks a bunch of formats but does not verify wether they are null, causing a crash. I cannot overwrite this class because when I try to get the formats in javax.sound.sampled.spi.FormatConversionProvider, it returns me an empty array if I don't use the default class ...

Here is the code that doesn't check null:

```
    public boolean isConversionSupported(AudioFormat targetFormat, AudioFormat sourceFormat){

         AudioFormat targetFormats[] = getTargetFormats( targetFormat.getEncoding(), sourceFormat );

        for(int i=0; i<targetFormats.length; i++) {
            if( targetFormat.matches( targetFormats[i] ) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean matches(AudioFormat format) {
        if (format.getEncoding().equals(getEncoding())
                && (format.getChannels() == AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED
                    || format.getChannels() == getChannels())
                && (format.getSampleRate() == (float)AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED
                    || format.getSampleRate() == getSampleRate())
                && (format.getSampleSizeInBits() == AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED
                    || format.getSampleSizeInBits() == getSampleSizeInBits())
                && (format.getFrameRate() == (float)AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED
                    || format.getFrameRate() == getFrameRate())
                && (format.getFrameSize() == AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED
                    || format.getFrameSize() == getFrameSize())
                && (getSampleSizeInBits() <= 8
                    || format.isBigEndian() == isBigEndian())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: if you are always using the same audio file, why not take the createAudio() function call out of the for loop and create it once before the for loop?

Comment: Because I want my function ConvertMP3.newRatedMusicFile() to be independant, it just asks for a directory, a source, a target and a floating number. In the future the song might change :/

Comment: I can’t see the relationship between you first loop and the next code snippet. If this is supposed to be part of the `createAudio` method, it’s not clear what it does with the parameters or how it alters the object’s state, most notably, where `this.source` is initialized or modified.

Comment: this.source is the "File" I am converting, which doesn't change throughout the loop and is only Read, not Written

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I finally resolved my problem, literally after hours of searching.

The fact is that the AudioInputStream or whatever was somehow drained when converting it (Yes that's annoying when classes are messing with your variables --)

Anyway, what I did was converting it instead to a ByteArray before doing my things.
Here is my new loop:

```
private void passRates() throws Exception {
    for (Float rate : this.rates) {
        AudioInputStream in = null;
        in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(this.directory + currentBeatmaps.get(0).getAudioFileName()));
        AudioFormat baseFormat = in.getFormat();
        AudioFormat decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                16,
                baseFormat.getChannels(),
                baseFormat.getChannels() * 2,
                baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                false);
        AudioInputStream din2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in);

        long length = din2.getFrameLength();
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(din2);
        in.close();
        InputStream is1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

        AudioInputStream din = new AudioInputStream(
                is1,
                decodedFormat,
                length
        );
        String audio = this.jInputAudioFilename.getText() + " x" + Float.toString(rate) + ".mp3";
        createAudio(din, this.directory, audio, rate);
        for (Beatmap beatmap : this.currentBeatmaps) {
            createRate(beatmap, audio, rate);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think this is optimized or anything, but this works perfectly

Note: This doesn't seem to work in some MP3 files. I have imported a few libraries and the AudioInputStream is created but when the FrameLength is unknown, IOUtils.toByteArray() gets stuck in an infinite loops because it is waiting for an EOF.